# Showing $||T||_{op}$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a normed vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}$.

Let $F \subset L(X,Y)$ (where $L(X,Y) = \{{A ∈ Hom(X, Y) | A  \ \text{continuous}} \} =
\{A ∈ Hom(X, Y) \ |  \ \ ||A||_{op} < ∞ \}$ )
such that ,

$\forall x \in X, f \in Y' (= L(Y,\mathbb{K}))$ and $T \in F$:

$\{|f(Tx)| \}$ is bounded

Show that $\{||T||_{op}  \ | \  T \in F \}$ is bounded.

Is this fairly trivial by the uniform boundedness theorem? and also by the fact that,

If you have a subset $M \subset Y$ of a normed vector space then,

$M  \ \ \text{bounded} \iff \forall f \in Y' : \{f(m) | m \in M\} $ is bounded

Comment: Yes, you are right. It follows from the fact that weak boundedness implies norm boundedness.

Comment: I think I have the intuition, do I need to show F is Pointwise bounded?

Comment: Is this stupid, If $F \subset L(X,Y)$ then is $T \in F$ an element of $L(X,Y)$ also so $T \in Hom(X,Y)$ and $||T||_{op} < \infty$ ?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thanks for commenting. Nevermind that last comment I think thats rubbish. Do I need to show $Sup\{Tx\} < \infty$ which implies that $||T||_{op} < \infty$ by uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will prove $$M \ \ \text{bounded} \iff \forall f \in Y' : \{f(m) | m \in M\} \text{ is bounded$$}$$ 
Forward implication  is trivial.

For the converse let $f(M) $ is bounded which means there exists a $M_f>0$ such that $$|f(m)|<M_f   \forall m$$
fix any $m\in M$. Concider $m^*\in X^{**}$ given by
$$m^*(f)=f(m)$$.

$$|m^*(f)|=|f(m)|\leq ||f||||m||$$
So $$||m^*||\leq ||m||$$

Also concider the linear functional on the subspace spanned by $\{m\}$ given by
$$f_m(cm)=c||m||$$ 
Then it is easy to see that $||f_m||=1$ and $f_m(m)=||m||$
ByHahn-banach theorem it has a norm preserving extension say $g_m$. Then 
$$||g_m||=1,  m^*(g_m)=g_m(m)=f_m(m)=||m||$$
Which proves that $||m^*||=||m||$
Now apply Uniform boundedness principle on $\{m^*(f):m\in M\}=\{f(m):m\in M\}$. For each $f$ the above set is bounded. Hence by uniform boundedness principle $$\text{sup}_{M}||m^*||<\infty\implies \text{sup}_M ||m||<\infty$$

Hence $M$ is bounded.

Now your question $\{f(T(x))\}$ bounded means $\{T(x)\}$ bounded by above result. Now again applying unifform bounded principle we can show $$\text{sup}_F||T||<\infty $$

Comment: Thank you, can you please clarify the last bit ? I am sorry I am new to functional analysis and trying my best to figure it out. By using the result you proved above does that not tell us that $F$ is bounded? $F$ bounded $\iff f(T), T \in F $ is bounded?

Comment: For uniform boundedness do I need $Sup\{Tx\} < \infty $? i.e. Pointwise bounded?

Comment: you are right..but if we take $S=\{ Tx:T\in F\}$ then $\{f(T(x))\}$ is bounded means $S$ is bounded

Comment: yes for uniform bounded you need $sup_{T\in F}||Tx||<\infty$

Comment: So $Tx$ bounded. Should we use some notion of Ball here? To ensure we can use supremum?

Comment: , You have proved that for a fixed $x\in X $ , $\{||Tx||:T\in F\}$ is bounded. Now directly you apply uniform bounded principle...to prove $$Sup||T||<\infty$$

Comment: I thought I had it but still not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31389/discussion-between-soumitra-and-sean).